# OWL-API get Inferred Individuals

Tags: java, owl-api, fact, inferred-type

I have an existing Ontology loaded inside a Singleton Class 'Ontology'.

I would like to have the corresponding inferred Ontology.

This is my actual code :

```
List<InferredAxiomGenerator<? extends OWLAxiom>> gens = new ArrayList<InferredAxiomGenerator<? extends OWLAxiom>>();
gens.add(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator());
gens.add(new InferredEquivalentClassAxiomGenerator());
InferredOntologyGenerator InferredGenerator = new InferredOntologyGenerator(Ontology.getOntology().getOWLReasoner(), gens);
                InferredGenerator.fillOntology(Ontology.getOntology().getOWLOntologyManager(), Ontology.getOntology().getOWLOntology());
```

That should add in my ontology all the infered axioms, right ?
Well it doesnt. I have a class SpeciesA :

```
SpeciesA ⊑ Species ⊓ ∃hasPart.Fruit
```

And so I created an Individual of Species which I added the property hasPart to another individual of Fruit.
Doing this in Protégé and generating the inferred ontology WILL tell me my Individual is of SubClass SpeciesA. But doing it in Java with the provided code doesnt work.

I use this to output the SubClasses of an Individual :

```
for (OWLClassExpression i :
Individual.getTypes((Ontology.getOntology().getOWLOntology())))
                   System.out.println("Inferred classes of Individual : " + i.toString());
```

And it actually outputs only the IRI of "Species" and not "SpeciesA".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which reasoner are you using?

Comment: I would expect this to work the same way through Protege or directly. Can you try another reasoner, just to see whether it's an issue with Fact or not? If that doesn't work please show how you create the reasoner and the ontology, and how you add the individual.

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much its working fine with Pellet!

Comment: Do you mind submitting this as a bug on fact++ or on jfact website?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer; I'm not sure I should submit this as a bug because I lately realized on the help file that the Individual Inferring function was stated as "not implemented yet" (as well as many other Inferring fuctions).